Copying format restarts a custom undo record
I'm developing a Word add-in using VSTO and faced an issue with a custom UndoRecord. The problem appears when I use the CopyFormat method between the StartCustomRecord and EndCustomRecord method calls. Executing CopyFormat causes the existing UndoRecord to close and start a new one. This results in an additional record appearing in the undo stack, which is not the desired behaviour.
Here is a simplified version of the method I'm using:
private static void PasteRtf(string rtf, Range sourceRange, Range targetRange)
{
    var undoRecord = sourceRange.Application.UndoRecord;
    try
    {
        undoRecord.StartCustomRecord("Custom record");

        targetRange.InsertParagraphBefore();
        targetRange = targetRange.Paragraphs.First.Range;

        System.Windows.Clipboard.Clear();
        System.Windows.Clipboard.SetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf, rtf);
        targetRange.Paste();

        sourceRange.Select();
        sourceRange.Application.Selection.CopyFormat();
        targetRange.Select();
        targetRange.Application.Selection.PasteFormat();
    }
    finally
    {
        undoRecord.EndCustomRecord();
    }
}

In the above code, StartCustomRecord is called at the beginning, and EndCustomRecord is called at the end. However, after executing CopyFormat, it seems that a new UndoRecord is created, which results in multiple undo actions for a single operation.
My questions are:

Why does CopyFormat cause a new UndoRecord to be created?
How can I prevent this behaviour and ensure that only one undo record is created for the entire operation?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

private static void PasteRtf(string rtf, Range sourceRange, Range targetRange)
{
    var undoRecord = sourceRange.Application.UndoRecord;
    try
    {
        undoRecord.StartCustomRecord("Custom record");

        targetRange.InsertParagraphBefore();
        targetRange = targetRange.Paragraphs.First.Range;

        System.Windows.Clipboard.Clear();
        System.Windows.Clipboard.SetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf, rtf);
        targetRange.Paste();

        targetRange.set_Style(sourceRange.get_Style());

        targetRange.Font.Name = sourceRange.Font.Name;
        targetRange.Font.Size = sourceRange.Font.Size;
        targetRange.Font.Bold = sourceRange.Font.Bold;
        targetRange.Font.Italic = sourceRange.Font.Italic;
        targetRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = sourceRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment;

    }
    finally
    {
        undoRecord.EndCustomRecord();
    }
}


Thank you for the response. Although it is an amazing workaround, it doesn't work well as I also need to copy the style from the source range to the target range.
